# Mediator C++ GUI sample

Tags: c++, design-patterns, mediator

I have heard that somewhere @ web I'll be able to find good C++ example of Mediator working with GUI components. But I menaged to find only that GoF sample or things from sorcemaking and similar that aren't helpful to me.

So... do you know where that mentioned GUI sample can be found?

Sorry for that kind of question, but that can be useful for others too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this one: http://www.andypatterns.com/index.php/design_patterns/model_gui_mediator_pattern/. It appears the author is applying the pattern specifically to the 'view' part of the GUI functionality (as opposed to the data modeling behind it).
Not sure if that's what you were looking for...